# Rails: Undefined method `in_pasting?' for Reline::ANSI:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have **Ruby 2.7.2** and **Rails 6.1.3.1** installed on my **Ubuntu 20.04** machine. However, when I try to test a ruby command using the command below:

```
irb
a = 1
```

I get the error below:

> /home/mycomputer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.3.5/lib/irb/ruby-lex.rb:50:in `block in set_input': undefined method` in_pasting?' for Reline::ANSI:Class (NoMethodError)

I am still tryring to fix it, but it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused by an issue with the [reline](https://github.com/ruby/reline) gem in the `Ruby 2.7.2` setup. However, if I switch to another Ruby version (`2.6.6`) using `rbenv global 2.6.6` everything seems to work fine.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

**Solution 1**:

Since the [reline](https://github.com/ruby/reline) gem comes with Ruby installations, we will uninstall the **ruby 2.7.2** version that is the cause of the issue using **rbenv** :

```
rbenv uninstall 2.7.2
```

Next, reinstall the **ruby 2.7.2** version that is the cause of the issue using **rbenv** :

```
rbenv install 2.7.2
```

Afterwhich you will install the version of **Bunder** and **Rails** that you are using. In this case, my Rails version is **Rails 6.1.3.1**:

```
gem install bundler
gem install rails -v 6.1.3.1
rbenv rehash
```

You can afterwards, check the version of ruby, bundler and rails that were installed using the command below:

```
ruby -v
bundler -v
rails -v
```

This time when you try to test again using `irb` it should work fine.

**Solution 2**:

A faster approach will be to uninstall the [reline](https://github.com/ruby/reline) gem in the `Ruby 2.7.2` setup using the command below:

```
gem uninstall reline
```

And then reinstall it:

```
gem install reline
```

**Note**:

I did not test this to confirm if it fixes the issue.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**